# When does a nonnegative $C^1$ function on $[a,b]$ have finitely many zeros?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

It is well known that if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is real analytic then we have that either $f\equiv 0$ or $f$ has finitely many zeros on the interval $[a,b]$.

It is also known that you can have a nonnegative function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ that is smooth with infinitely many zeros on $[a,b]$. A bump function, for example.

My question is:

> Given a nonnegative function $f\in C^1([a,b],\mathbb R)$, not identically $0$, is there an additional constraint other than analytic that tells you that $f$ has finitely many zeros?

Comment: How about "$f$ is strictly monotone"?

Comment: @WillieWong Or more generally, one condition is that $f'$ has finitely many zeros.

Comment: I think one has to be a bit careful about your first sentence. What precisely do you mean by analyticity on a *closed* set?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Sorry, I meant analytic $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and then study the zeros on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @WillieWong and user168590: And then, by induction, ... :-)

Comment: Analyticity is pretty much the largest regularity class that avoids bump functions.  Gevrey classes, for instance, are the most popular class used between the smooth and analytic classes, and they support bump functions also.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class